# Coldfusion list apend on click

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page containing a `<table>`. Each row contains a checkbox. Whenever one of the boxes is clicked, I need to add the value of that row to a list. How can get it to add values to the list on click without having to go to an action page?

The reason I want to do this on click is so I can show a summed value of the items as each item is clicked. The code below gives me the list I need I just need it to update it on click. I'm guessing I need a javascript function, but I'm pretty new to this.

```
<cfset number = #form.chkbx#>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ListLen(form.chkbx)#">
   <cfif form.chkbx neq 0>
   <cfelse>
     <cfset "vote_number#number#" = #ListGetAt(form.chkbx, i, ",")#>
     <cfset number  = number >
   </cfif>
</cfloop>

<!--- this is just to get rid of an extra digit i get in the end --->
<cfif ListLen(number) GT 1>
   <cfset number = ListDeleteAt(number,ListLen(number))>
</cfif>


<!--- 
     My code for the check box preparing it for a javascript 
     function I haven't figured out yet 
--->
<CFOUTPUT query="qGetOpenItemsTrans">
<TR><TD> <input type="checkbox" 
              name="chkbx"id='#ID#' 
              value="#seq_claim_id#"
              onclick="UpdateCost('#ID#')" 
              unchecked = 0>

    </TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Inventory_Date#</TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#seq_claim_id#</TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Month_Closed#</TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Amount_Rcvd_by_FRG#</TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Commission_Amt#</TD>
    <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Net_Recovery#</TD>
</TR>
```

im very new to this and i did look over jquery but i have no idea where to begin to make this work. i found a piece of jquery but it needs the user to click a button and will alert each item that is checked but what i need a a comma delimmeted list of the values of the ones checked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sbt_alert_checked_checkbox_val').on("click", function(e){

    $('input[name="chkbx"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    alert( $(this).val() );
    })

    e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

Im getting much closer to what i need! issue with this piece of code is that it worked when checking the checkboxes then clicking a submit button that would alert the list of values. i cant seem to get it to work for a "Check Box" each time a checkbox is checked maybe i can get a clue here

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#chkbx').click(function() {


var slvals = []
$('input:checkbox[name=chkcountry]:checked').each(function() {
slvals.push($(this).val())
})
alert('Selected Checkbox values are: ' + slvals)
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: This definitely would be better suited by javascript (I see that you have already tagged it for javascript). You should provide your checkbox code.

Comment: Put the code in the question....not in a comment. The formatting in comments is abysmal for code.

Comment: You are trying to run server side code (the ColdFusion part) in a client side process (the clicking checkbox part). That won't work unless you make an AJAX call. However, you need not do that. Using a library like jQuery will make this task extremely simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are definitely on the right track using jQuery to solve the problem. It sounds like there are a few different things you are trying to accomplish with this script, so I am going to make a few assumptions and try to show you something that should do what you want it to do.

To attach the event handler to the checkboxes you could use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    // test click handler with an alert. this.value
    // 'this' is the checkbox that was clicked. Access the value using dot notation.
    alert(this.value); 
});
```

That will alert the value of any checkbox you click. Now, from your description I understand that you don't want to alert the results, but this will let you know that your click handler is working. If I understand what you are trying to do, you will need to put two function calls into this handler function.

The first function will create a comma delimited list containing the values of the checkboxes that have been checked.

```
function createDelimitedList() {
    var list = '';
    // loop over each checkbox on the page
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function( index ) {
        // if the checkbox is checked, add its value to the list
        if ( this.prop("checked") ){
            if ( index == 0 ){
                list += this.value;
            }else{
                list += ',' + this.value; 
            }
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

Add the function call to the event handler and now you have a list that you can do stuff with.. I'm not sure what you want to do with it, but you could, say, use jQuery to assign the value to a hidden field so that on form submit you can pass the value into some Coldfusion code.

Next you need to create your running sum for the values clicked.  This is going to be super similar to the list function.

```
function getCheckboxSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    // loop over each checkbox on the page
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function( index ) {
        // if the checkbox is checked, add its value to the list
        if ( this.prop("checked") ){
            sum += this.value;
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

Now every time a checkbox is clicked you have code that gets all of the checkboxes on the page that are clicked and creates a comma delimited list and a sum of the values. You will need to modify this a bit to make sure that you are getting the desired values, I just assumed that you would be using the value of the checkbox field, but you can use jQuery to get the value of any field on the page inside the `each` loop in your functions.

So now your handler function should look like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    var list = createDelimitedList();
    var sum =  getCheckboxSum();        
    // now write some code to put the values where you want them
});
```

This code makes a few assumptions about the layout of your html, and comes without warranty haha, but this is typically how I would approach a similar problem.